# Pass an initial value to a Django form field

Tags: django, django-forms

Django newbie question....

I'm trying to write a search form and maintain the state of the input box between the search request and the search results.

Here's my form:

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    q = forms.CharField(label='Search: ', max_length=50)
```

And here's my views code:

```
def search(request, q=""):
    if (q != ""): 
        q = q.strip()
        form = SearchForm(initial=q) 
        #get results here...
        return render_to_response('things/search_results.html',
          {'things': things,  'form': form, 'query': q})
    elif (request.method == 'POST'): # If the form has been submitted
        form = SearchForm(request.POST) 
        if form.is_valid(): 
          q = form.cleaned_data['q']
          # Process the data in form.cleaned_data
          return HttpResponseRedirect('/things/search/%s/' % q) # Redirect after POST
        else:
          form = SearchForm() 
          return render_to_response('things/search.html', {
            'form': form,
          })
    else:
        form = SearchForm()
        return render_to_response('things/search.html', {
            'form': form,
        })
```

But this gives me the error:

```
Caught an exception while rendering: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'get'
```

How can I pass the initial value? Various things I've tried seem to interfere with the request.POST parameter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Several things are not good here...

1) The recommended thing after a POST is to redirect. This avoids the infamous popup saying that you are resubmitting the form when using the back button.

2) You don't need to say `if request.method == 'POST'`, just `if request.POST`. That makes your code easier to read.

3) The view generally looks something like:

```
def myview(request):
    # Some set up operations
    if request.POST:
       form=MyForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
          # some other operations and model save if any
          # redirect to results page
    form=MyForm()
    #render your form template
```

That is not to say that there can't be much simpler and much more complicated views. But that is the gist of a view: if request is post process the form and redirect; if request is get render the form.

<strike>I don't know why you are getting an unicode error. I can only think that it is related to one of your models that you don't provide.</strike>
The error, as spookylukey mentions is in his comment, most likely is caused by you submitting a string instead of a dict to the initial parameter.

I really recommend the django documentation, in [particular the tutorial.](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/#intro-tutorial01), but there is also the very nice [Django Book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/).

All that said, I think you want something like:

```
def search(request, q=None):
    if request.POST:
        form = SearchForm(request.POST) 
        if form.is_valid(): 
           q = form.cleaned_data['q']
           url=reverse('search_results', args=(q,))
           return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
    if q is None:
        form = SearchForm() 
    else: 
        form = SearchForm(initial={'q': q})
    return render_to_response('things/search.html', {
        'form': form,
    })
```

Notice that the parameter to initial is a dict of the field values of your form.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The error is due to passing a unicode object instead of a dict. (dict defines 'get()', but string/unicode does not).

Comment: Ah, excellent point. I saw the error but didn't make the connection!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed comments, and the solution. I'd implemented it this way because I wanted the results URLs to look like /search/query (I know there are problems with this, though, and may well revise it). I do redirect after the POST, so there is no problem with pressing the Back button.

Answer (score 5):

Django forms are not particularly helpful for your use case.  Also, for a search page, it's much better to use a GET form and maintain state in the URL.  The following code is much shorter, simpler and conforms far better to HTTP standards:

```
def search(request):
    q = request.GET.get('q','').strip()
    results = get_some_results(q)
    render_to_response("things/search.html", {'q': q, 'results': results})
```

The template:

```
<form method="GET" action=".">
<p><input type="text" value="{{ q }}" /> <input type="submit" value="Search" /></p>
{% if q %}
   {% if results %}
       Your results...
   {% else %}
       No results
   {% endif %}
{% endif %}
</form>
```